# Angular - How can I move ngClass logic from template to ts file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-class

In Angular application I am using dropdown filters for user selection. I have add logic in ngClass

`<div [ngClass]="i > 2 && 'array-design'">`

How can I move the logic for classed to the controller? As when they are in the template it not possible to unit test them.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="searchFilters.length > 0; else loading">
        <div class="filter-items" *ngFor="let filter of searchFilters; index as i">
            <div [ngClass]="i > 2 && 'array-design'">
                <app-multi-select [items]="filter.navigators" [title]="filter.name"></app-multi-select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

.scss

```
  .cross-reactivity, .array-design{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
```

Comment: You can do `[class]="classExpression"` and set the `classExpression` value somewhere in ts: preferrably in some lifehook before the view initializes, or at least in ngAfterViewInit - all depending on the way you get vars involved in the logic for the class. The `classExpression` can be a space-delimited string of class names, an object with class names as the keys and truthy or falsy expressions as the values, an array of class names - so you have variety of options.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind writing it down for me? Would be more clear for me. I am new to ANgular

Comment: Your solution isn’t actually that bad.. also - why and how would you want to test this anyway? It’s not a test you can really do in your unit tests and in a cypress e2e test, your solution is still testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the conditional statement into a function and use its return in HTML.

---

html

```
[ngClass]="filterClass(i)"
```

ts

```
const filterClass = (i) => i > 2 && 'array-design';
```